# Echo error message if query result is empty

Tags: php, database, mysqli

How can I add another error message if the query is empty? I tried with `mysqli_num_rows` without success. :/

```
$que = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$tbl = $que->query
("
 SELECT iditem, nazwa
 FROM  `idlist2` 
 WHERE nazwa LIKE  '%$name%'
");

while($value=$tbl->fetch_assoc())
{
    if(strlen($name) == 0 || strlen($name) == NULL)
    {
        echo '<font color="green">!</font>';
        break;
    }
    echo $value['iditem'] . $value['nazwa'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: count($tbl->fetch_assoc())

Comment: Can you add the `mysqli_num_rows` usage? I'd have thought that would work

Comment: As @Andrew pointed out, a simple counting of the number of results would be sufficient in this use case

Comment: the real question here is the failed mysqli_num_rows as @user3783243 mentiones, which wasnt added to the Q

Comment: @Andrew wouldn't `count($tbl->fetch_assoc())` just count the columns in the fetched row, or try to count(null) if there were no rows to fetch?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I dont know I dont use mysqli, thats why its a comment :P But the idea is ok, if you have the data, count the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
while($value=$tbl->fetch_assoc())
{
    $notempty = true;                              // set a variable if you fetch anything
    if(strlen($name) == 0 || strlen($name) == NULL)
    {
        echo '<font color="green">!</font>';
         break;
    }
    echo $value['iditem'] . $value['nazwa'] . "<br>";
}
if (!isset($notempty)) {
    echo 'other error message';                   // show the other message if it isn't set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing this the wrong way. `mysqli_num_rows` is used when you are querying in a procedural manner.

In your code sample, you created a new object by calling `new mysqli()`. To get the number of rows fetched when using OOP construct, you should get the value of `num_rows` property.
And this is how to go about that:

```
if ($tbl->num_rows > 0) {
    while($value=$tbl->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if(strlen($name) == 0 || strlen($name) == NULL)
        {
            echo '<font color="green">!</font>';
            break;
        }
        echo $value['iditem'] . $value['nazwa'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
        echo "No result found";
}
$que->close();
```